# Concatenate - adding instead of appending

Tags: python

I am running the following python file that is supposed to concatenate the content of files from multiple folders into one csv with a common header file.The contents of the files are being concatenated as needed, but the results are being added, not appended.

This is an example of the result I am getting:

[image]

This is an example of what I need:

[image]

Here is the code of the python file, with the variables removed for clarity:

```
import sys
import re
import os

frequencyCount = {}

with open(sys.argv[1] + '/Concatenated.csv', 'w+') as outfile:
try:
    with open(sys.argv[1] + '/MatrixHeader.csv') as headerfile:
        for line in headerfile:
            outfile.write(line + '\n')
except:
    print 'No Header File'


                    //vars were in here
                    //built columnTuple

                    if url in frequencyCount:
                        frequencyCount[url] = tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(frequencyCount[url], columnTuple))
                    else:
                        frequencyCount[url] = columnTuple

# write the tuples to stdout
# Note: they are unsorted
for url in frequencyCount.keys():
    writeString = url
    for col in frequencyCount[url]:
        writeString = writeString + "," + str(col)
    writeString = writeString + "\n"
    outfile.write(writeString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because of the `sum` you are using here`tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(frequencyCount[url], columnTuple))`? I think you should get rid of the call to `sum`.

Comment: yes that does seem to be it; what would be the best remedy for this?

Comment: Try to get rid of the call to `sum` function. `tuple(t for t in zip(frequencyCount[url], columnTuple))`.

Comment: @mic4ael Don't even need the generator expression. `tuple(zip(frequencyCount[url], columnTuple))`